# Oddity in rxplot

Tags: ros, rxplot, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi..

I try to "rxplot" but the rxplot does not show anything in window..
I have made "rostopic echo /kirim_ke_servo" to see the data

> name: ['joint1',
> 'joint2',
> 'joint3']
>
> position: [-0.6512382961093546,
> -0.19887827975841985, 1.568777172497011]
>
> velocity: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

So, I try to "rxplot /kirim_ke_servo/position" in terminal

> rizqa@ubuntu:~$ rxplot
> /kirim_ke_servo/position
>
> [/kirim_ke_servo/position] value was
> not numeric: (-0.8225104223257155,
> -0.07641244134696615, 1.755642665868377)

In terminal appear the data.. but rxplot does not display anything
How fix the problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60194/oddity-in-rxplot/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rxplot can only plot numeric values. The "/kirim_ke_servo/position" argument you are using is an array of numeric values, hence rxplot complains. Off the top of my head,

```
rxplot /kirim_ke_servo/position[0]
```

should work. This way, the argument points to the first numeric_value in the array. You can of course also plot multiple values simultaneously as described on the [rxplot wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot). There's also [rqt_plot](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_plot), last time I checked it didn't work with array values like yours though (might have changed now).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-04-08**:
nice... ^_^
it works.. thanks @Stefan Kohlbrecher

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-07**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher See [my answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/60194/oddity-in-rxplot/?answer=60203#post-id-60203) for array plot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As in @Stefan Kohlbrecher's answer, there's [rqt_plot](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_plot) that supersedes `rxplot` (in fact, all `rx` tools are succeeded by [rqt](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt)). Please open an enhancement request ticket [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues?sort=updated&state=open) if you think it's useful to many users.

---

Update)
[rqt_plot](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_plot) does accept brancket to identify elements in the array.[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-04-08**:
okay.. thanks @Isaac Saito ^_^